Engage the community with Topic Weeks? Suggest topics!
Here is an idea I've been toying around with for a while.
Topic Weeks.
The concept would be this:

Every week Once a month for a week, we select one tag
The tag wiki gets fleshed out in advance
The tag gets an introduction post on meta, requesting questions about tag
The introduction post is promoted on Bitcoin communities
At the end of the week we tally up the questions that got asked

The idea would be to focus on topics that are popular in the community but so far have gotten little attention on Bitcoin.SE. Via the promotion the questions would get more attention than usually and hopefully better answers. We'd help develop understanding in the community about the topic. We might attract a few new users and improve meta activity.
What are your thoughts on this? What topics do you think would do well?

related: How do weekly topic challenges work?

I like the idea. What are some ideas you have for future weekly topics?

@2quick4u: Don't know exactly yet. SegWit could be interesting with the upcoming 0.13.1. Mimblewimble would be nice to hear more about. I don't think it would be particularly hard to find a few topics, but the echo was rather lukewarm, especially since I had featured this question on the main site for almost a month.

I would be interested in learning more about mimblewimble. Unfortunately I do not know if the most "interesting" topics will always correlate with a large number of questions.  However even with low question volume the weekly focus would seem to increase the chances of high quality answers which was one of your goals

@2quick4u: It seems obvious that our taste would differ from that of the broader audience. It would be good to switch off with less arcane tags. – I'd love to have an accomplice for this. Would you be interested in collaborating to introduce this? Perhaps in parallel to Monero.SE and Bitcoin.SE?

I would love to collaborate on sometime. Let me think about how we can best mutually benefit from this and talk to the Monero SE community. Can I get back to you in a few days to discuss more specifics?

@2quick4u: Sure, I'm not going anywhere.

So, one topic that comes up on Reddit a lot lately is the lightning-network. There is some confusion about it, and some honest differences in opinion how it would work out.
We currently have 17 questions about it.
A lot of people have some sense of what it is, but I imagine that there are quite a few open questions.

We're got a lot of good ground covered on that tag, but we don't have a general intro/"What is lightning?" question

@NickODell: I'm on it: What is the Lightning Network proposal? What problem is it trying to solve?
